# ASP.NET Core 3.1, handle multiple route parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have small API which serves files. The requested file is coming from our ClickOnce app. Instead of multiple `GET` actions which will go into the requested folder/file, is it possible to have single `GET` action which from I can get all the route parameters so I can build my relative path.

Example `GET` routes

```
/api/ApplicationFiles
/api/ApplicationFiles/somefile
/api/ApplicationFiles/someFolder/somefile
/api/ApplicationFiles/someFolder/someFolder/someFolder/someFile
```

So I have to define multiple `GET` endpoints.

Comment: First can you please show the code.. a fully reproducible example and the actual output plus the expected output?  Second have you thought of just using Query String parameters instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an asterisk to indicate that your route parameter can contain slashes. This is called a [catch-all parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-template-reference), and looks like this:

```cs
[Route("/api/ApplicationFiles/{**path}")]
public IActionResult GetFile(string path)
{
    // code
}
```

From the documentation:

> You can use an asterisk (`*`) or double asterisk (`**`) as a prefix to a route parameter to bind to the rest of the URI. These are called a catch-all parameters. For example, `blog/{**slug}` matches any URI that starts with `/blog` and has any value following it, which is assigned to the slug route value. Catch-all parameters can also match the empty string.
>
> The catch-all parameter escapes the appropriate characters when the route is used to generate a URL, including path separator (/) characters. For example, the route `foo/{*path}` with route values `{ path = "my/path" }` generates `foo/my%2Fpath`. Note the escaped forward slash. To round-trip path separator characters, use the `**` route parameter prefix. The route `foo/{**path}` with `{ path = "my/path" }` generates `foo/my/path`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to define multiple route attributes for a single controller method. Have a look at this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis

```
[Route("~/api/ApplicationFiles")]
[Route("~/api/ApplicationFiles/{somefile}")]
[Route("~/api/ApplicationFiles/{someFolder}/{somefile}")]
[Route("~/api/ApplicationFiles/{someFolder}/{someFolder2}/{someFolder3}/{somefile}")]
```

where `somefile`, `someFolder`, `someFolder2`, and `someFolder3` are string parameters of your controller method

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to get rid of.